# How can I generate a persistence.xml tailored for each of my arquillian tests?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss-arquillian

I am learning Arquillian to see if I can add to it project.

I was able to create a test and deploying a "static" test-persistence.xml, similar to [this tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#write_the_test).

My problem is that my real persistence.xml has different mappings () and entities (). To get my tests to work I have to either:

1. Add all classes and mappings to the persistence.xml, which will cause every test to have to insert all entities and mappings to the package and would add cost of maintenance to the test-persistence.xml/tests when new entities/mappings are added to the system
2. Somehow add the mappings/entities on-the-fly to my persistence unit
3. Pre-generate the persistence.xml before creating the package to deploy
4. Have one persistence.xml for each TestCase

Alternative 4 is not feasible, since it can't be maintained.
Alternative 1 is feasible, but I would like to keep my builds smaller.
I tried both 2 and 3, but I was not able to find any way (I am using JavaEE, JPA 2.0 and Hibernate) to make any of them. It seems that Hibernate does not support adding entities/mappings on-the-fly and that Archive.AddAsResource accepts just a path, not a "file content", or something like this.

I think this is a common issue when testing with Arquillian. How can I build my persistence.xml in a way that it has only the things  required for my test?

Comment: Why don't you use annotations for the entities and mappings? In that case you wouldn't need to add these to all `persistence.....xml`

Comment: Annotations are used in most of the cases, but in some of them they are not and this is a legacy thing I can't change. About the mappings: they have to be set on an entity, but this is some times not the best place to do so, so we decided to map them be ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a test version of your persistence.xml stored as a separate file in your source tree, and have ShrinkWrap add it to your test archives as a file asset.

```
return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)  
             .addAsManifestResource(new FileAsset(new File("src/test/resources/META-INF/test-persistence.xml")), "persistence.xml");
```

Comment: Ok, great, but then in my persistence.xml I have <class>MyClass1</class>...<class>MyClass50</class>. I will have to add all 50 entities even though my test just uses 1 on them?

Comment: Just add the entities you need in your test-persistence.xml and leave remaining out.That way you have separate persistence for test environment

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not understand what you mean. Arquillian's approach is to make one deployment for each TestCase and each test case will test a differente feature. So I would have one test-persistence.xml for each test case? I didn't count exactly, but my feeling is that I would get easily around 20 test-persistence.xml

Comment: Use can try ShrinkWrap descriptors if you don't want to maintain different files

Comment: That would be great, do you have any resource about it?  My research led me to the code, but it doesn't seem to have documentation about it, so I am not able to integrate with the deployment at the moment